# Javascript fill the form which you must to type on that

Tags: javascript, autofill

This site : https://launch.stellar.org/#/login

When I used

```
$("#username").val("1234");
$(".btn-default").click();
//The site has jquery
```

I got a message:

> Username and password cannot be blank.

Although the username was filled .
I tried many code but it still not working .

Comment: Not only have you not filled in the password, the site checks for a `:focus` event or a `click` in the input or something similar, so setting the value using JS flies under the validator's radar. That being said, why are you trying to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This site stores the current value of event 'change', if you change values in DOM of this input it's not firing event 'change'.

Because of that script not storing that change and saying that there's nothing in that input element.

I think you need fire event 'change' on #username and then click submit button.

//I was late, @Huey already answered